# Check specific row word count in text file based on starting row values

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have text file having content like this below format:

```
0001EPP000000084906875   00000   0001 
0002EPP000000084906875   00016   0002
0003EPP000000084906875       

............


0001EPP000000084967647   00001  0002 
0002EPP000000077676678   00016  0002
0003EPP000000084777770
```

I need to loop through all the rows, find the row starting with 0001 and 0002 need to get the corresponding row word count for the same (0001, 0002) with the count, I will do further calculations ...
For this, I have done this:

```
string filename = string.Empty;
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] TXTFiles = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");
foreach(var file in TXTFiles)
{
    filename = file.Name;
}


var reader = new StreamReader(filename);

foreach(string item in File.ReadAllLines(filename))
{
    // Here I need to check the file content 
}
```

Please, could anyone help on this? How to identify the row content and get the word count, if row content matches starting criteria?

Comment: Are the rows tab separated? You can split each row into a string array. Then analyse the items, if (items[0].Substring(0,4) == items[2]) {  }

Comment: Do you know of the FileHelper library ? It's very good and efficient when coming to manipulating text file (reading and writing, in both delimited and fixed-length format.

Comment: I am not supposed to use any third part library

Comment: it's a free library :-) 
Are your text files following a strict format ? is it fixed length? Is it one big file or many files ?

Comment: You could use `item.StartsWith("0001")` to do a comparison on the text at the beginning of the row. Your question isn't quite clear on what other data you need to extract, but I suspect `item.EndsWith("0001")` (to compare the end of the line) may be of use too.

Comment: @James I am getting error at "File.ReadAllLines(filename)"   file not found exception .. even i am reading it from my local folder could you pls help on this ..

Comment: If you're getting an Exception, then that's what you should have been asking about in the question ! Remove the line `var reader = new StreamReader(filename);` because you are not using the reader and it may be locking the file. Set a breakpoint at `File.ReadAllLines()` and see what the value of `filename` is. Make sure that it is the full path to a file.

Comment: `file.Name` is just the name of the file, which doesn't include the path. You should replace that with `file.FullName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can change that should get you where you want to be.

First, you can get rid of the `StreamReader` line, since `File.ReadAllLines` is all we need to get the contents.

Second, we should put the code that processes the file inside the `foreach (var file ...` loop. Otherwise, we're only processing the last file.

Third, you should replace `file.Name` (which is just the filename) with `file.FullName` (which includes the full path and file name). Otherwise, you will likely get a `FileNotFoundException` unless you happen to be searching in the current directory.

And finally, when reading the file, we can use `StartsWith` to check if the line starts with the text you're looking for, and when we find the line we want, we can use `string.Split` to break it on the space character into an array. Then it's just a matter of reading the parts you care about from the line.

The code would then look something like this:

```
var path = @"c:\public\temp";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles("*.txt"))
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName))
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("0001") || line.StartsWith("0002"))
        {
            var lineParts = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            // This is assuming that the word count is in the column (which has index 2)
            if (lineParts.Length > 2)
            {
                var wordCount = lineParts[2];
                Console.WriteLine($"Found data in file {file.Name}:");
                Console.WriteLine($" - Line starts with {lineParts[0].Substring(0, 4)}");
                Console.WriteLine($" - Has word count of {wordCount}");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]